# How to decrypt ECDSA_secp256k1 private key from PEM format generated with OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key-generation, pem, ecdsa

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted ECDSA_secp256k1 private key generated using the OpenSSL CLI command `openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 | openssl ec -aes-128-cbc -out ecdsa_priv.pem` but I want to do it using pure Javascript. I tried using [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge), [asn1js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asn1js) and [pkijs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkijs) but without success.

Example encrypted key:

Note: I believe the **hexValue** is the **IV** (initialization vector) used to generate the key

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC, `hexValue`

`encrypted key`
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Basically the steps that I'm trying are:

1. Extract the decryption algorithm - **AES-128-CBC** from the example and the **IV**
2. Applying the PBKDF2 function - i.e: pbkdf2Sync() function from [crypto](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-pbkdf2sync-method/) with the password that I know that the given key is being encrypted with in the first place, `""` empty string as a `salt`, `1` as `iterations` and `"sha1"` as `digest` because I've read that these are the default values that OpenSSL uses under the hood. And I want the `keylen` of the `derivedKey` to be `16`.
3. Then create a custom decipher with `crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', derivedKey, iv);`
4. Then call `await Buffer.concat([decipher.update(pemHex), decipher.final()]));`
5. And get this `error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`

Using `node-forge`, I got the farthest as I got actually a decrypted private key but it is different than the one that I want to get (I know what should be the decrypted private key in the end). As I dug deeper I saw that generating a `derivedKey` with the same arguments with both `node-forge` and `crypto` was yielding different keys. As I read PBKDF2 should be deterministic, so I assume `node-forge` implementation differs somehow and thats why the private key that I'm comparing it to also differs

Can someone please give me some guidance on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not PBKDF2, it's not SHA1, and it's not unsalted. OpenSSL's 'legacy' or 'traditional' privatekey (PEM) encryption uses OpenSSL's `EVP_BytesToKey` which is based on (in this case equal to) PBKDF1, with MD5 n=1 and using the DEK-info value *both* as salt (for 8 bytes) *and* as IV -- this differs from (old) `openssl enc` which is provided as (deprecated) `create{Cipher,Decipher}` in nodejs crypto.

The following code does the decryption; since you give no clue what you want to do with the result, I just write it back out in unencrypted PEM format:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

let file = 'se270720.eky', pw = 'password';
var lines = fs.readFileSync(file,'ascii').split('\n');
if (lines[0].startsWith('-----BEGIN ') && lines[0].endsWith('-----')
&& lines[lines.length-1] == ''
&& lines[lines.length-2] == lines[0].replace('BEGIN','END')
&& lines[1].toLowerCase() == 'proc-type: 4,encrypted'
&& lines[2].toLowerCase().startsWith('dek-info: aes-128-cbc,')
&& lines[3] == '' ) {
  var saltiv = Buffer.from(lines[2].substring(22),'hex');
  var key = crypto.createHash('md5').update(pw).update(saltiv.slice(0,8)).digest();
  var decr = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc',key,saltiv);
  var ctext = Buffer.from(lines.slice(4,lines.length-2).join(''),'base64');
  var plain = Buffer.concat([decr.update(ctext),decr.final()]);
  var newbody = plain.toString('base64').replaceAll(/.{64}/g,'$&\n');
  console.log([lines[0],newbody,lines[lines.length-2],''].join('\n'));
}
```

As in your question this uses nodejs `crypto` which is of course not pure Javascript. Pure JS would vary quite a bit depending on what library(s) you use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I needed to tweak a bit here and there, but the essential part did the job and I'm very grateful! Thanks also for all the clarifications about the process!